# Convert StorageFile to string

Tags: c#, uwp

We need to store an image file as a string in a UWP app. This was the plan:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);
string fileString = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

but the line

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);
```

throws

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'C:\MyFolder\ImageFile.png' is denied.

For this exercise Everyone has Full Control permission on the file. I've also moved the file to various locations including a USB stick but always get the same exception. I assume this is a UWP thing rather than a permissions thing?

How do we save an image file as a string in a UWP app?

Comment: Instead of reading the file with `File.ReadAllBytes`, I'd expect you to `FileIO.ReadBufferAsync` etc - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#reading-from-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the exception, because in UWP you only can access to files over the path, is in the App-Package area.

To solve your problem you can use the [`IBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer) extension `ToArray`:

```
 IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
 string fileString = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly access to a file with string path. In UWP, you should always access file with Storage(File, Folder)[check this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/)
to get Bytes, you can use FileIO class or Open Stream with StorageFile.